# SQL: Date format and Case Statement Question

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have some dates in the following format :   `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`’

I would like it to be in this format: `YYYY-MM-DD`

Also, I am selecting another field with true and false values which I would like to convert to 0's and 1's

Is this possible?

**I am doing this in a dts package and noticed one more thing:**

The last field I am selecting is a guid which is enclosed in {brackets} is there a way to take the brackets out

Comment: Do you really mean "DTS package", or are you working with a SSIS (Integration Services) project?? SQL Server "Denali" (2011) will drop support for DTS packages.....

Comment: Right now it is in a dts package that i will later convert to ssis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are using SQL Server 2008, then there is a `DATATYPE` DATE, without time. You could `CAST` your date column to this format or convert it to `VARCHAR(10)` using the 120 format. So, if you are writing a query, you can use the following statement for your columns:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,DateColumn), /* Or CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateColumn,120) depending on what you want*/
        CASE BooleanColumn WHEN 'False' THEN 0 WHEN 'True' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(GuidColumn,'{',''),'}','')
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The date format that you see is defined by application you use. So with out that information is hard to answer. With the boolean is the same situation.